# Optimize UPDATE statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-administration

In MySQL I have a table with almost 100 columns  and 33 000 rows of data stored in it. And i'm trying to run a procedure that will update all the columns in a table or insert new row in a table according to some condition. Something like that:

```
IF (v_Rows > 0) then
UPDATE tab1 SET
col1 = var1,
col2 = var2,
. . .
col95 = var95
WHERE id = var_id
 ELSE
insert into tab1 values 
(var1, var2, ... var95)
END IF;
```

These statements takes too much time to execute. And I'm curious about how such structure can be optimized?

Comment: Search for "UPDATE IF EXISTS ELSE INSERT" implementations on Google

Answer (score 1):

See [*`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

It uses a unique key to decide whether the row already exists, then...

- If it does not exist, it `INSERTs`;
- If it does exist, it updates whatever you specify.

Use `col22 = VALUES(col22)` to avoid having the 'update' to the `var22`, which is already provided.  See [*`VALUES()`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values).

If you have multiple rows to apply at the same time in the same way,

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, ...)
    SELECT col1, ... FROM source_tbl ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY col1 = VALUES(col1), ...;
```